# Dynamically change options of a jQuery plugin with callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a plugin that is instantiated with default settings, with the possibility of overriding them, for example:

```
$('#test').Plugin({
  option1: 'blahblah',
  option2: 'test'
});
```

It also has the possibility of adding callbacks like this:

```
funcCallback = function(t){
    //Do something with t to change option1
};

$('#test').Plugin({
  option1: 'blahblah',
  option2: 'test',
  callback: funcCallback
});
```

Inside the plugin I can see that the callbacks are like this:

```
if (this.settings.callback) {
  this.settings.callback.call(this);
}
```

If there a way to change `option1` and `option2` with that callback? I know I can create a function inside the plugin to specifically change the settings, but I would like to use the plugin unchanged.

Comment: Short answer is no. You would need to amend the plugin to expose its internal settings object for you to be able to amend it from within the callback. If it doesn't do that by default, then you cannot achieve what you require here.

Comment: Wouldn't the context be the plugin itself, as it is being bound via the **call** invocation? Thereby `this.settings.option1` and `this.settings.option2` should work.

Comment: Answer really depends on how plugin is constructed. what plugin is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context will be the plugin itself, as it is being bound via the `call` invocation.

```
funcCallback = function(t){
    this.settings.option1 = 'newblahblah';
};
```

Comment: So simple... I kept insisting on doing t.settings.option1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the design of the plugin. For example, the jQuery UI plugins generally allow you to change options dynamically by using the `option` method, like this:

```
$("#test").dialog("option", {
    autoOpen: true,
    disabled: false
});
```

If the plugin is written using the [jQuery Widget Factory](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/) I think it gets this automatically.

But I've seen many simple plugins that don't provide any way to modify the settings dynamically. Instead, you may have to create a new element and initialize the plugin with the new options.